# Get input values from a specific div after drag and drop in flask

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flask

I'm writing a little program to generate code templates for projects. The idea is to have a bunch of boxes with inputs in them and using drag and drop to order them in another place. Then push a button and the code gets generated considering the names and args provided within the individual boxes.

I'm not sure if i'm explaining it right, but here's my code for further understanding.

I'm not new to Flask, but I'm a total newbie in HTML + CSS + Javascript.

First html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.css') }}">
<body>
    {% block content %}
    <section id="container" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="template" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" name="class">
              <div class="title">Class Template</div>
              <label for="classname" id="classname">Name</label><input class="classname">
              <label for="argsname" id="argsname">Args</label><input class="argsname">
            </div>
            <div class="template" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2" name="function">
              <div class="title">Function Template</div>
              <label for="funcname" id="funcname">Name</label><input class="funcname">
              <label for="argsname" id="argsname">Args</label><input class="argsname">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="droparea" id="droparea" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        
      </section>
      <div id="buttons">
        <input type="button" class="submit" value="Generate Code">
      </div>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
<script type=text/javascript src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/dnd.js') }}"></script>
</html>
```

This is the CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 680px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}
.flex-container {  
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  
}
.droparea {
 flex-grow: 1;
 flex-direction: column;
}
#droparea {
 background-color: #ebe7e7;
}

.submit {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.template {
   margin: 10px;
   height: 80px;
   width: 200px;
   background-color: #54a1c0c9
}

.template > label {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

.template > input {
  margin: 1 5px 1 5px;
  
}
```

Now the Drag and Drop (dnd.js) file:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
   ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

So, the drag and drop works, but I don't know how to obtain the values from the inputs within the droparea div after pressing the button. I have been investigating and tried an AJAX snippet but it didn't work. I just need a guide please, thanks.

The data retrieved from the inputs should be strings.